# Seedstack JMS listener enable disable from properties file

Tags: properties, jms, listener, disable, seedstack

I have 4 JMS listener classes. Sometimes I need to stop a listener (e.g. if the queue attached to this listener is not working). Is there any way to stop the listener from properties file using some flag so that I don't need to change in Java listener class and redeploy the application?

I'm using the IBM MQ JMS client implementation.

Comment: IBM MQ is being used

Comment: For what it's worth, the Seedstack project seems to have been largely abandoned. There have been no releases in a couple of years. Furthermore, there's only 1 thread in the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/seedstack) they use for support and only 42 total questions on Stack Overflow [tagged with `seedstack`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seedstack) (2 of them from you). This indicates a low level of adoption which is not surprising given the lack of development activity. You might consider moving to a different framework/platform.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the [Seedstack JMS documentation](http://seedstack.org/addons/jms/) that would indicate any ability to disable a listener via a properties file or any other dynamic way.

Furthermore, I don't believe the IBM MQ JMS client implementation has support for this kind of functionality either.